# How to do this in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[I am a beginner in android I want to open a setting popup when the user clicks on the setting button as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j3vW.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is called [Bottom Sheet Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog). For details, [here](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/android-bottom-sheet-5b64ddb3c02d) is a blog post on how you can implement it.